# Nanoc + Bower = Error - Found 2 content files for

Tags: ruby, bower, nanoc

I'm using nanoc to generate an static site.

Recently I added [Bower](https://github.com/twitter/bower) to manage front end dependencies.

When I add Bootstrap via Bower I place the package in `/assets/bower/`

The Bootstrap package contains multiple files, including:

```
bootstrap/js/tests/vendor/qunit.css
bootstrap/js/tests/vendor/qunit.js
```

My `Rules` file has these rules:

```
route '/assets/*' do
  extension = item[:extension]
  if extension == 'coffee'
    extension = 'js'
  end
  item.identifier.chop + '.' + extension
end

compile '*', :rep => :spec do
  if !item[:spec_files].nil? && !item.binary?
    filter :erb
    layout 'spec'
  end
end

route '*', :rep => :spec do
  if !item[:spec_files].nil? && !item.binary?
     '/specs' + @item.identifier[0..-2] + '.html'
  end
end

compile '*' do
  if !item.binary?
    filter :erb
    layout_name = item[:layout] || 'default'
    layout layout_name
  end
end

route '*' do
  if item.binary?
     item.identifier.chop + '.' + item[:extension]
  else
     item.identifier[0..-2] + '.html'
  end
end
```

When running `nanoc` I get the following error:

```
 RuntimeError: Found 2 content files for
 content/assets/bower/bootstrap/js/tests/vendor/qunit; expected 0 or 1
```

I tried adding 2 new 'empty' rules for the /assets/bower/ folder but still getting the error.

```
route '/assets/bower/*' do
end

compile '/assets/bower/*' do      
end
```

Any  suggestions?

**Later edit:**

Looks like nanoc supports a static datasource that also takes in consideration the file extension.

https://github.com/nanoc/nanoc-site/blob/master/content/docs/troubleshooting.md

Still not sure if I can use both data sources in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't have two files in the same directory with the same name before the last extension. For nanoc 4.0 it'll be rewritten to change that.

You can definitely have multiple data sources used at once, but that means you can't apply filters to the `qunit` files, only redirect the output.

Do you explicitly have to be able to organise files the same as Bower installs them? It might be a better idea to split them up into `scripts` and `styles` if you can, anyway - you'll almost certainly be filtering based on filetype, anyway, and that means in Rules you can just go

```
compile '/whatever-path/scripts/' do
    filter :concatenate
    filter :uglify_js
end
```

rather than

```
compile '/whatever-path/ do
  case item[:extension]
  when 'js'
    filter :uglify_js
  when 'scss'
    filter :sass
  end
end
```